# Possible ways to check if a value exists in a sequence scala

Tags: scala

```
case class dummy(val prop:Seq[Test])
case class Test(val s :String)
case class Result(val s :String)

def myFunc:Result = {
  val s = "11,22,33"
  val t = Test(s)
  val list = dummy(Seq(t))
  val code = Option("25")
  val result = code.exists(p => {
    list.prop.exists(d => d.s.split(",").contains(p))
  })

  if (result) {
    Result("found")
  } else {
    Result("Not Found")
  }
}
```

I am calling function `myFunc`, but instead of evaluating a boolean using if/else construct.

Any possible ways to avoid using If else construct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with using the `if/else`, but you could do this:

```
code
  .flatMap(c => list.prop.find(_.s.split(",").contains(c)))
  .map(_ => Result("Found")).getOrElse(Result("Not Found"))
```

The idea here is that instead of returning a `Boolean` at each stage we are passing an `Option` along.  Then at the end if the `Option` is defined we can map that into a `Result("Found")`, and if it is not defined the `.getOrElse` will return a `Result("Not Found")`.